# Enable GPU tracing with ADB

Tags: android, profiling, adb, gpu

I'm developing an Android application that uses OpenGL ES and due to some reasons I cannot launch it from Android Studio but I am building it using command line and installing (and optionally launching it) through adb commands.

Now I want to monitor the CPU as well as the GPU but in the second case I got this error

> "Rooted device required The device needs to be rooted in order to
>   launch an application for GPU tracing. To trace your own application
>   on a non-rooted device, enable tracing in the run configuration"

[image: Cannot profile GPU]

As I said I am not launching the app from AS and I have no option to root the device. Does anybody know a way to launch the app "enable tracing" using adb?

Answer (score 1):

To edit the run configuration choose "Run/Run..." in AndroidStudio and then select "Edit Configurations". Choose tab "profiling" and there select "Capture GPU Commands".

Rooting the device should not be necessary as far as I know.

Comment: I did that but I still get the same error message... In the device Settings, under Monitoring, I have Profile GPU rendering set to "In adb shel dumpsys gfxinfo", and Enable OpenGL traces to "Systrace (Graphics)".

Comment: I was clicking "Debug" instead of "Run"... ^^; Now I get a trace but the app stops immediately on start and Android Studio shows "Failed to connect to the graphics debugger" :(